# How to specify multiple forms with Mesosphere in Meteorite?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I have multiple forms I'd like to declare but it appears you can only do one at a time:

```
Mesosphere({
    name: "signupForm",
    method: "signup",
    fields: {

        username: {
            required: true
        },

        email: {
            required: true,
            format: "email",

        password: {
            required: true,
        }

    }
});

Mesosphere({
    name: "loginForm",
    method: "login",
    fields: {

        usernameOrEmail: {
            required: true,
        },

        password: {
            required: true,
            }
        }

    }
});
```

It doesnt appear that it possible to pass in an array or multiple objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it currently does not support specifying multiple forms at once. If you would like to swing by github and file an issue as a feature request to remind me. I'd be more than happy to include this in a future release. http://github.com/copleykj/Mesosphere